# Does a Spring controller returning a ListenableFuture needs @AsynchEnable in configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As of [spring 4.1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements), spring controllers accept return value that can be of type ListenableFuture. is returning a ListenableFuture return value sufficient in making the controller async? Or does it also need @enableAsync annotation somewhere in spring configuration file or/and anything else? I am following this [tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/09/asynchronous-spring-service/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that what i was looking for is not @enableAsync but a servlet 3.0 property called async-supported. According to this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1665), spring-boot defaults async-supported to true.

Hence, there is no need of any further configuration to do if you're using spring-boot.